# How to add extra components to DataGrid row MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm trying to add extra components to a row in a MUI DataGrid.

For example, in the DataGrid below, I want to add some text below the main contents of a row. (Notice row ID 5's First name column's value)

[image: desired_output]

Is there an API available that allows for this kind of modification without having to modify the core components? If not, how can I create a customized component that allows for this behavior?

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o54y9v?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `renderCell` property in the field. Inside the return you can write you component like you would do normaly.

```
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <Stack>
          <span>{params.value}</span>
          <span>Your extra text</span>
        </Stack>
      );
    }
  },
...
]
```

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-demo-mui-x-forked-ke1esc?file=/demo.js:156-490) based on your code

Comment: The `params` here is kind of ambiguous (as it is in a lot of the MUI documentation), so I just wanted to mention that includes much more than just the value of the field – including the values of the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

*The functionality of `renderCell` is limited to cells.*

---

*If your question is more general & require more customizations:* 
***How to customize each row as a React Component in DataGrid MUI?***

#### in short

use **`<DataGrid slots={{ row: ProjectInfoRcompDto }}`**

where the `ProjectInfoRcompDto` is your **custom** React component

- takes a **`props`** of type `GridRowProps`
- where the **`props.row`** gives you access to **each row** (--ie: each row of `arr_ProjectInfo` in `<DataGrid rows={arr_ProjectInfo}`)
- needs to return the **resultant-rendered Component** of each Row.

-

- (note: the default value of `row` is `GridRow` --ie: `slots={{ row: GridRow }}`)

#### code ex

```
class ProjectInfo {
  public readonly name: string;
  public readonly arr_urlStr: string[] = [];
  public readonly arr_imgInfo: ImgInfo[] = [];
  public readonly arr_pathStr_vid: string[] = [];
  public readonly flexGrow = 1;
  public readonly seqAddedDate;
  public readonly lvOfComplexity;

...

const arr_ProjectInfo_ori: readonly ProjectInfo[] = [

...


function App() {
  const [arr_ProjectInfo, set_arr_ProjectInfo] = React.useState(arr_ProjectInfo_ori.slice());

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={muitheme_DataGrid}>
      <Box>Full Stack Developer / Data Analyst</Box>

      <DataGrid
        rows={arr_ProjectInfo}
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={(row) => row.name}
        // columns={columns.map((column) => ({
        //   ...column,
        //   // renderCell: (params) => <ProjectInfoRcomp projectInfo={params} />,
        //   renderCell: (params) => <div>8888888{params.value}</div>,
        // }))}
        // slots={{ row: GridRow }}
        slots={{ row: ProjectInfoRcompDto }}
      />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

// no_knowlres // check the jsdoc found default GridRow -> GridRowProps
const ProjectInfoRcompDto: React.FC<GridRowProps> = (props) => {
  // console.log(props);
  // console.log(props.row);
  if (!(props.row instanceof ProjectInfo)) {
    console.log('not_sure_Api');
    // throw new TypeError('not_sure_Api');
    return <div>not_sure_Api</div>;
  }
  return <ProjectInfoRcomp projectInfo={props.row} />;
};
```

---

---

***Update:***

##### 1.

if you wonder what `ProjectInfoRcomp` is (/ how to use it) , 
it just a component that takes data from `props.row`, and returns your desire layout 
-- just a general normal React component you write everyday -- nothing special

---

*for the comment below*

##### 1.

> add an extra row below the `<GridRow>`

- maybe you should do sth like

  ```
  const ProjectInfoRcompDto: React.FC<GridRowProps> = (props) => {
    // const { scale_Proj_rst, ...props_less } = props;
    return (
      <>
        <GridRow {...props} />
        {/* <div>your extra row</div> */}
        {props.index === 1 && <div>your extra row</div>}
        {
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid]; props.index === 1 && (
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];   <GridRow
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];     {...props_less}
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];     index={20}
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];     // ;; rowId="ARandomAddedRow"
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];     row={new ProjectInfo('ARandomAddedRow', ['https://aaa'], [], [], 1, 11, 2.5)}
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid];   />
          // ;not_working[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid]; )
        }
      </>
    );
  };
  ```
- if you really want to add a row,, that **has the same format** as the default `GridRow`, 
  seems **not possible**, 
  as the code shown above >"[seems the rows are fixed onec pass in `rows` to DataGrid]"

##### 1.

> the table row width keep expanding non stop

I tried the default `GridRow`, the same happened to me, idk why.

I have to **disable `columnVisibilityModel`**, idk why.

```
<DataGrid 
  // columnVisibilityModel={{ arr_urlStr: false, seqAddedDate: false }}
```

##### 1.

> the default inner layout components of `<GridRow>`

Not sure.

I think this is the source code: 
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/86ac3d2b90da1f889fe47d5f7a7930fc97b8ed23/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/components/GridRow.tsx#L103C7-L103C15

##### 1.

(*Im not an expert on this, I just tried these out, can be wrong*)

Comment: hi, I want to add an extra row below the `<GridRow>`, but when I put `<GridRow>` inside a `<Box>`, like `<Box><GridRow /> {"something"} </Box>`, the table row width keep expanding non stop, where can I find the default inner layout components of `<GridRow>`?

Comment: @yeln (see reply in my updated answer)